# During a sys call, who checks if the address is writable

Tags: c, memory, kernel, system, system-calls

So, consider a sys call that returns struct (like `gettimeofday`).

Now, I do the following call

```
gettimeoftheday(&time, NULL)
```

Now, when the sys call is called I am aware that the kernel checks if the right parameter have been passed for the syscall. But in this case, is it the job of the kernel to check if the pointer `time` is writable?

Comment: This would trigger a seg-fault just like in any other situation, right?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean 'the job of the kernel'?

Consider a **malicious** piece of code trying to break the kernel, passing an address of something in the kernel. If the kernel did not have proper mechanisms it would corrupt its own state. Moreover, the address could be plain invalid.

In short, **of course** the kernel has to check it. In linux they do access_ok() for range checking and have separate __put_user / __get_user (and other) primitives to actually access stuff - these fail if read/write was not possible.

Comment: This is documented in the man page: upon failure `gettimeofday()` shall return -1 and the only documented reason for failure is: `[EFAULT]  An argument address referenced invalid memory.`